# Running Metadata API in Apex as a specific user

Tags: webservices, metadata-api, callout

Calling the metadata API in Apex requires admin permission (or at least the "Modify All Data" access). To run the code as a non-admin user I am thinking I need to first login as the sys admin, get a session ID, pass it to the request header, and then make the call. The problem is, I don't know how to do it inside Apex!

More precisely I need the `readMetadata()` method in the Metadata API to run as an admin user. Here's how the method currently looks:

```
    public MetadataAPI.IReadResult readMetadata(String type_x,String[] fullNames) {
        MetadataAPI.readMetadata_element request_x = new MetadataAPI.readMetadata_element();
        request_x.type_x = type_x;
        request_x.fullNames = fullNames;
        MetadataAPI.IReadResponseElement response_x;
        Map<String, MetadataAPI.IReadResponseElement> response_map_x = new Map<String, MetadataAPI.IReadResponseElement>();
        response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
        WebServiceCallout.invoke(
          this,
          request_x,
          response_map_x,
          new String[]{endpoint_x,
          '',
          'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',
          'readMetadata',
          'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',
          'readMetadataResponse',
          'MetadataAPI.read' + type_x + 'Response_element'}
        );
        response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
        return response_x.getResult();
    }
```

Basically it's about unwrapping the WebServiceCallout class (it's what SF uses to call its API), putting the session ID into its header, and then re-wrapping it.

Let me know if you have any ideas to share!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Seems like it's be easier to just grant the user(s) in question the permission needed?

Comment: Because I want to replicate listviews in our portal app, and to get listviews we need to use the metadata api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Wsdl2Apex based class will include some additional parts that identify the session.

There will be an inner class that contains the `readMetadata` method. It will probably be called something like MetadataPort or MetadataService. This class will include members like:

```
public soapSforceCom200604Metadata.SessionHeader_element SessionHeader;
private String SessionHeader_hns = 'SessionHeader=http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata';
```

It `SessionHeader` here contains the active SessionId of the user who is making the request. If you replace the value with the SessionId of a user with the "Modify All Data" permission then the call should succeed.

The trick then becomes how does a non-admin user get a valid admin users session.

If you had access to the admin users credentials, say via a protected custom setting that is hidden in a managed package, then you could call the login method via the Partner API to get a valid session.

Better yet, try using an oAuth flow to get a refresh token that can be used to get a valid session id. That way you only need to securely store the refresh token rather than the admins un and pw.